# Number of transactions

Tags: transactions

I was having a look at the number of transactions in the bitcoin address for bitcoin.org.

I went to blockchain.org explorer. It says https://blockchain.info/address/1GwV7fPX97hmavc6iNrUZUogmjpLPrPFoE

No. Transactions    354

I have exported the CSV, and sorted it by "x" that is the number of each time they received some funds. The output I had is 365.

I am confused about these numbers. It is not possible that the total of funds received are higher in the CSV, than the number of Tx's.

Not sure what I am missing here.

By the way, I wanted to get people to donate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` field is not the time that of each transaction they received. `x` is a date is unix epoch time and `y` is the number of transactions that were received during that day. Since you probably exported the number of transactions for the past year, you got 365 days of data so your count of `x`s results in 365. But that is not what you want, you want to sum the `y` values.

Comment: Dear lord. Ok. So now it should make more sense 8.75 BTC received in 70 Tx's, in the last year.